# How to center a circular progress bar after rotating it with an animation in Android?

Tags: java, android, layout, progress-bar

Before rotation animation it's great, but I don't like where the circle beggins, I'm getting this:

http://s3.postimg.org/ptnap4h8h/cnocorrido.png

After applying rotation animation I'm getting this:

[image]

I have one circular progress bar which I had to rotate it in order for it to start from the bottom and end at the bottom

Circular progress bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="7.0"
            android:useLevel="true">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#fb0000"
                android:endColor="#00FF00"
                android:centerColor="#fbf400"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It has a text view(answerCountdown) in the middle of the circle that shows the seconds left. That's working perfectly.

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/barTimer"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gameCountDown"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/answerCountdown"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gameCountDown"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But after I apply a rotation animation It's not centered, it goes to the left or right depending on the angle you rotate it, the code on the count down Timer

```
 Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90.0f, 250f, 273f);
    an.setFillAfter(true);
    barTimer.startAnimation(an);
```

The textView is already centered perfectly, is there any way to "center after rotation" without having to enter margin values on the layout?....I just wanna work it out with one layout file for the moment........

Comment: Have you set the pivot points to be at the centre of the circle?

Comment: How do I do that? Will that help to see it centered in a Cellphone screen as well as in a Tablet screen?.....All the code related to the progress bar is posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive your constructor is off:

```
Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90.0f, 250f, 273f);
```

The 3rd and 4th parameters represent the rotation pivot points and should look more like the following

```
Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90.0f, .5f, .5f);
```

The above means: Rotate from 0 to 90 degrees with the X and Y pivot points at wherever 50% of the image is.

Source: [Android Documentation: RotateAnimation(float, float, float, float)](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html#RotateAnimation(float,%20float,%20float,%20float))

Comment: I tried what you suggested, I changed just those last values exactly like you but the circle it's still not wrapping the number....this was the result

http://s14.postimg.org/u1ujxodsh/Sin_t_tulo.png

Comment: After trying different values I was able to solve it. Your answer was right my friend. There was just something missing on my animation code, all of the other code was l left it exacly as posted, the difference is this, I added the line   barTimer.setAnimation(an);, I forgot to assing the an

    final RotateAnimation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90.0f,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
        an.setDuration(0);
        an.setFillAfter(true);
        barTimer.setAnimation(an);
        barTimer.startAnimation(an);

Comment: Here's the final result, I leave it for future help to users trying to accomplish the same

http://s27.postimg.org/c5h71dvtf/finalresult.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/barTimer"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:max="100"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerCountdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="jfi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, I already solved it with Tambykojak answer!! Check the replies to see the solution!! I was missing the assignment of the animation to the progressbar